# git submodule update fails when using access token

Tags: git

1. I created a Personal Access Token in git, and stored it in
   GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN environment variable on a Linux VM.
2. I cloned a github repo I own into the VM.  The repo contains a submodule.
3. I ran `git submodule init` which returned:   `$ git submodule init Submodule '<path>' (https://${GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN}@github.com/<user>/<repo>.git) registered for path '<path>'`
4. I ran `git submodule update --recursive` which hangs at `$ git submodule update Cloning into '<my_path>'...`
5. If I instead just clone something like:
   `https://${GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN}@github.com/<user>/<repo>.git` the cloning
   works
6. I tried the same process on a raspberry pi with Raspbian and got at step
   4: `Cloning into '<my_path>'... Password for 'https://${GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN}@github.com': remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead. remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information. fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/' fatal: clone of 'https://${GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN}@github.com/<user>/<repo>' into submodule path '<my_path>' failed Failed to clone '<my_path>'. Retry scheduled`
7. Again I tried step 5 on the Raspberry pi and the clone proceeded
   correctly.

Has anyone seen this behavior before? Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Per https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials "Git will sometimes need credentials from the user in order to perform operations; for example, it may need to ask for a username and password in order to access a remote repository over HTTP....."

In this case, set environment variable GIT_ASKPASS to a function that returns the GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN.  For example:
`export GIT_ASKPASS=$HOME/path/to/git_askpass.sh` where:

git_askpass.sh:

````
#!/bin/bash
echo $GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN```
````